# How to delete a Grant by GID

Tags: users

Typically grants are deleted by `$nid` whenever new grants are added.  In fact this function is baked into [node_access_write_grants()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access_write_grants/7) (when `$delete = TRUE`).

I have been using custom GID's to represent different users's Address IDs (`$aid`).  When a user edits his/her address I want all the old grants with that GID/AID to be deleted but leave the grants on the particular node to be untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear to me that Drupal 7 has no built in way to delete grants by GID, only by `$node`. Because of this I'm advocating doing a simple database query very similar to the query in [node_access_write_grants()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access_write_grants/7).

Original:

```
 if ($delete) {
    $query = db_delete('node_access')
             ->condition('nid', $node->nid);
    if ($realm) {
      $query->condition('realm', array($realm, 'all'), 'IN');
    }
    $query->execute();
 }
```

My code:

```
$query = db_delete('node_access')
         ->condition('gid', $address->aid);
$query->execute();
```

Perhaps there's something to be said for using the 'realm' field to circumvent this issue.  However, this seems to work.  I'd love to know what the community thinks.